# How to set different css files for each store in custom module

Tags: magento2, css, multistore, less

I created a `module` which is changing some of the behaviours on the bundle product. I also need to create some `CSS` and I did create a file and attach in a layout by doing this:

```
<css src="Bachus_BundleContextPros::css/bundle_style.css"/>.
```

Now the problem is that the store is `multi-store` with different colour shapes.

My question is how do apply to different versions of my `bundle_style.css` for **each store** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to copy that CSS file in : `/web/i18n/code_ISO/css/style.css` then your css will be loaded for that store So:

1. > app/code/Bachus/BundleContextPros/view/frontend/layout/bachus_bundlecontextpros_index.xml

   ```
   ...
   <head>
       <css src="Bachus_BundleContextPros::css/bundle_style_store1.css"/> //french store for exemple
       <css src="Bachus_BundleContextPros::css/bundle_style_store2.css"/> //English store
       <css src="Bachus_BundleContextPros::css/bundle_style_store3.css"/> //Russian store
   </head>
   ...
   ```
2. > app/code/Bachus/BundleContextPros/view/frontend/web/i18n/fr_FR/css/bundle_style_store1.css
   >
   > app/code/Bachus/BundleContextPros/view/frontend/web/i18n/en_US/css/bundle_style_store2.css
   >
   > app/code/Bachus/BundleContextPros/view/frontend/web/i18n/ru_RU/css/bundle_style_store3.css
3. Deploy the static content :

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

Comment: what can be done if its for website not store?